# Matching records with wild cards from two different tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables with the following data (amongst other data).

**Table 1**

```
Value 1
'003232339639
'00264644106272
0026461226291#
```

I need to match the second column in the table below using column 1 as an identifier

**Table 2**

```
Value 1      Value 2
00264        1
0026485      2
0026481      3
00322889     4
00323283     5
00323288     6
```

So the results I need will be as follows:

**Result**

```
Table 1, Value 1   Table 2, Value 2         
'003232339639......4
'00264644106272....1
0026461226291#.....1
```

Any help will be appreciated - very stuck here and doing it manually at the moment in excel.

I hope this format makes sense - first time I am using this forum.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. How are 003232339639 and 00322889 related?

Answer (score 0):

Melany, the question is kind of confusing (not written correctly) perhaps that's why no one is responding. I'll make an attempt to explain how similar selects is done

SELECTING DATA FROM TABLE1 WHERE A MATCHING COLUMN (COL1) EXISTS IN BOTH TABLE

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
    INNER JOIN TABLE2
      ON TABLE1.COL1 = TABLE2.COL1
        AND TABLE1.COL1 = 'XYZ'
```

> USING A SUBSELECT FOR THE SAME

```
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1
            WHERE COL1 IN(SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE2
                           WHERE COL1 = 'XYZ')
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, the wildcard for one or more characters is `%`, and is to be used with the keyword `LIKE`.

So I suggest the following (if your purpose is really to match rows in `Table1` for which `Value1` begins like a value in `Table2.Value1`):

```
SELECT Table1.Value1, Table2.Value2 WHERE Table1.Value1 LIKE CONCAT(Table2.Value1, '%');
```

Edit: replace `CONCAT(x, y)` with `x || y` for some DBMSs (SQLite for instance).